Math symbols in minted
Greetings to TeXperts out there,
I am trying to write some code in a minted environment, but I am struggling with the "greater-or-equal" symbol. "≥" is not displayed at all (compiles to a blank space), while "\geq" is just displayed as "\geq", not as the greater-or-equal symbol.
I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong, but I just cannot find the mistake... Any suggestions?
Here is an MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{text}
       MWE
       -->≥<--
       \geq
    \end{minted}
\end{document}

Thanks in advance
Best regards

As always on this site, you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and play with as is. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

How are you compiling? pdflatex or an unicode-aware engine like lualatex?

Behavior is actually the same with pdfLatex and LuaLatex (though the original project is compiling with lualatex)

@DBa The behaviour is the same, but the solution is different :)

As you are using an unicode-aware engine, you'll just need to pick a monospaced font which has the glyph.
To find out, which fonts on your computer have the symbol, type
albatross ≥

in a terminal and pick a monospaced font from the results.
MWE:
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Mono}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{text}
       MWE
       -->≥<--
       \geq
    \end{minted}
\end{document}



It works with Arial on Overleaf (this is where I am compiling), do you by any chance know any location of a font gallery there?

@DBa https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions%2FWhich_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Monospaced_fonts

May I know what does % !TeX program = txs:///arara actually do? Or how to use it?

@Diaa It is a magic comment for texstudio, which selects how the document should be compiled. I'm using arara here, because it makes it easy to specify within the document which engine shall be used and to switch on shell-escape.

I apologize for the second off-topic comment, but I get %!TeX program not recognized! (txs:///arara). Any help is highly appreciated.

@Diaa In texstudio preferences -> build: add the following user command https://i.sstatic.net/pLv8XIfg.png

If you are tied to pdflatex, you can fake the symbol. I also add ≤ for completeness.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newif\ifmintedsub
\newunicodechar{≤}{\ifmintedsub\fakelgeq{<}\else\ensuremath{\leq}\fi}
\newunicodechar{≥}{\ifmintedsub\fakelgeq{>}\else\ensuremath{\geq}\fi}
\newcommand{\fakelgeq}[1]{%
  \texttt{%
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr#1\cr\noalign{\kern-0.3ex}-\cr\noalign{\kern-0.7ex}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\AddToHook{env/minted/begin}{\mintedsubtrue}


\begin{document}

$a\leq b ≤ c$

$a\geq b ≥ c$

\begin{minted}{text}
MWE
-->≥<-- y≥g≤h
\end{minted}

\end{document}


If you prefer that ≥ in minted is aligned with >,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newif\ifmintedsub
\newunicodechar{≤}{\ifmintedsub\fakelgeq{<}\else\ensuremath{\leq}\fi}
\newunicodechar{≥}{\ifmintedsub\fakelgeq{>}\else\ensuremath{\geq}\fi}
\newcommand{\fakelgeq}[1]{%
  \texttt{%
    \vtop{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr#1\cr\noalign{\kern-0.3ex}-\cr\noalign{\kern-0.6ex}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\AddToHook{env/minted/begin}{\mintedsubtrue}


\begin{document}

$a\leq b ≤ c$

$a\geq b ≥ c$

\begin{minted}{text}
MWE
-->≥<-- y≥g≤h
\end{minted}

\end{document}


Caveat
Different fonts might need adjustments in the spacing used inside \ialign. Experiment.
